# How to determine which Windows update, updates a specific DLL?

Tags: windows-xp, sql-server-2005, windows-update

The combination of Windows XP SP2 and SQL Server Express 2005 SP3 can causes the machine to blue screen during the installation of SQL Server Express. One of the Windows Updates that you can apply to Windows XP SP2 fixes the problem. Unfortunately, if you install Windows XP SP2 and run Windows Update, it will tell you that it needs to install about 118 updates. I would like to know which of the 118 updates fixes the problem. I know that the fix involves updating SXS.DLL to version 5.1.2600.3019.

Other than installing each update one at a time and checking the version of SXS.DLL after each update, is there an easier way of determining which update fixes the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The specific version of sxs.dll that you refer is from [Microsoft Security Bulletin MS06-075](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/security/Bulletin/ms06-075.mspx).

How do you know that the bsod is fixed in that specific version?

**Update to comment:** I think that its not so simple. As explained in [kb824994](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/824994) there are two branches in windows fix/update land. except from the usual one. There is the quick fix engineering one. Maybe the fix you need is on that branch. So installing only the security bulleting wont install the fix you need. If you really want to update sxs.dll just look for the latest hot fix including it you can find. I have found [kb943232](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/943232).

Comment: Just through testing. It's actually fixed by an earlier downloadable 'hot fix' but it appears that it is also fixed by a later 'Windows Update'.

Comment: The Windows Update referenced in the article Microsoft Security Bulletin MS06-075 does fix the SQL Server 2005 SP3 blue screen issue. The Windows Update is number is 926255 and is only applicable to XP SP2 (XP SP3 updates SXS.DLL).

Answer (score 3):

Yes: put it into Google. Every Microsoft KB article about a hotfix shows the version numbers of replaced files, so it's quite easy to found the article referencing the update you're looking for.

http://www.google.it/search?q=SXS.DLL+5.1.2600.3019
http://www.microsoft.com/technet/security/Bulletin/ms06-075.mspx

About those 118 updates: why don't you want to install them? And why not install SP3? Updates are released for a reason (fix bugs, close security holes, etc.), you shouldn't run a plain Windows XP SP2 system in the year 2009.

Unless you have a really good reason for doing that, of course (like incompatible software); but if you are one of those people who just don't want to "lose time" installing updates, I strongly advise you against this; it's a really good way to look for troubles.

Comment: Rather than tell the customer they have to install ALL the updates or Windows XP SP3, we would like to tell them which specific update that they need to install. It's about minimal machine impact.

Comment: Agreed on the minimal impact issue, but I'm still heavily convinced that running an obsolete and unpatched O.S. release is just asking for **much more** impact in the long term.

Answer (score 1):

After posting this question I decided that I could probably determine which updates, update this file (SXS.DLL) by grep'ing the .log files in the C:\Windows folder after installing all of the updates. These log files list which DLLs are being updated along with version information.